# Zend - plugin Word_CamelCaseToDash was not found in the registry

Tags: php, zend-framework

There is many topics like that all over the internet, but because i have NO IDEA what to do with answers i must ask it again.
I was transferring website from one server to another and after transfer i saw:

```
exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'Word_CamelCaseToDash' was not found in the registry; used paths:
Zend_Filter_: Zend/Filter/' in /library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412
Stack trace:
#0 /library/Zend/Filter/Inflector.php(518): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('Word_CamelCaseT...')
#1 /library/Zend/Filter/Inflector.php(411): Zend_Filter_Inflector->_getRule('Word_CamelCaseT...')
#2 /library/Zend/Filter/Inflector.php(311): Zend_Filter_Inflector->addFilterRule(':module', Array)
#3 /library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(281): Zend_Filter_Inflector->addRules(Array)
#4 /library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(381): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->getInflector()
#5 /library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(469): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->_getBasePath()
#6 /library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(516): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->initView()
#7 /library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(253): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->init()
#8 /library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(132): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->__construct(Object(ErrorController))
#9 /library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(262): Zend_Controller_Action->__construct(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http), Array)
#10 /library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#11 /index.php(39): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#12 {main}
```

Honestly i have no skill in Zend, so if anyone could tell me what is wrong with it? (website worker on previous hosting without a problem).

Comment: Is all your files uploaded

Comment: Yes, all files are uploaded (done full download/upload several times already to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

A file named **`CamelCaseToDash.php`** under **`Word`** directory is missing check that file first.

If the file exist than check in your configuration file whether the [**autoloadnamespace**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.examples.html) is for **Word** is added